# мне нужно чтобы вывелась статья, но выдает ошибку. Почему?

Tags: python, json, url

```
import json
from urllib.request import urlopen
from webbrowser import open_new


url = 'http://fakty.ictv.ua/ru/index/read-news/id/1571335'
data = urlopen(url).read().decode('utf8')
data = json.loads(data)
print(data)
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы бы хотя бы текст ошибки процитировали. Попробую телепатию.

Открыл вашу ссылку http://fakty.ictv.ua/ru/index/read-news/id/1571335
Выдается обычная страница. Естественно, при попытке распарсить JSON ничего не получится.
Если вы уверены, что сервер должен отдавать JSON, возможно, необходимо что-нибудь сказать серверу? Например 
Accept: application/json